# ffmpeg overlay rotated images onto a video, how to transparent the output area not covered by the rotated image?

Tags: images, ffmpeg, transparency, rotate

I am using `ffmpeg` to overlay a picture on a movie. The requirement is to rotate the picture through an arbitrary angle. Using `filter_complex`, I can overlay the rotated picture now. However, the output area of the picture is filled in black and not transparent. I checked the [docs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate), it says can specify the fill color, according to [this](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color), but I failed to do so. Any ideas?

I copy my command line here:

```
./ffmpeg -i mersyvideo.mp4 -i avatar.jpg -filter_complex "[1:v] rotate=-30*PI/180:c=black@'0x00':ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10" -codec:a copy output/overlayavatar.mp4
```

Comment: Have you tried this? `-vcodec png -pix_fmt bgra overlayavatar.mov`

Comment: sorry, but i am not using any PNGs with alpha channel. besides, I do not want to transparent the picture itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill the non-covered areas with transparent, use the option `c=none`:

```bsh
ffmpeg \
  -i mersyvideo.mp4 \
  -i avatar.jpg \
  -filter_complex "
  [1:v]rotate=-30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih)[rotate];
  [0:v][rotate]overlay=40:10
  " \
  -codec:a copy \
  output/overlayavatar.mp4
```

See the [`rotate` filter help](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#rotate):

> `fillcolor`, `c`
>
> Set the color used to fill the output area not covered by the rotated
> image. For the general syntax of this option, check the
> (ffmpeg-utils)"Color" section in the ffmpeg-utils manual. If the
> special value "none" is selected then no background is printed (useful for example if the background is never shown).
>
> Default value is "black".